# Swift - Tap a button when "done" from the keyboard is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfielddelegate

I have this situation :

[image: screenshot of my app]

And I would like to when the user taps on "Done" from the keyboard, it automatically taps on the "Sign in / Sign up" button.

I've read that :

My class should follow the protocol `UITextFieldDelegate`

Set the delegate of the password field `passwordTextField.delegate = self`

Then do something like this :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // releasing the focus on the textField and hiding the keyboard
        passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.tapOnSignIn()
        return true
    }
```

Then I created the function tapOnSignIn

```
func tapOnSignIn() {
        self.signinupButton.sendActions(for: .touchDown)
    }
```

But when I tap on the "Done" button from the keyboard, nothing happens.

Comment: why don't u call the method that you use inside the signinupbutton ?

Comment: What do you mean ? signinupbutton is a UIButton! . Do you mean calling the @IBAction func signinupTapped for example ?

Comment: what is the method you call in your button? don't you use performSegue or something inside?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer :

I need to call the action for my button and pass `self` as parameter :

```
self.signinupTapped(self)
```

Here's my function now :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // releasing the focus on the textField and hiding the keyboard
    passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.signinupTapped(self)
    return true
}
```